# want a single icon on AD user desktop on windows 2008 server r2 enterprise edition

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008

i want to create a single shortcut icon on Active Directory user desktop.
How do i create a shortcut that is displayed on all Active Directory users desktop?

Comment: This sounds like an admin question - this is a developer site; you might be better of in serverfault.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make your shortcut. It mast lead to network share that all have permissions to.
In GPO you have objects( user desktop to) Expand (in GPO)  Users Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates. Add shortcut and make gpupdate /force on client machine.

Comment: in GPO in Users Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\ desktop\desktop and there you have add\delete items. You can add your shortcut here.

Answer (score 0):

COPY THE ICON IN PUBLIC/DESKTOP FOLDER OF ADMINISTRATOR USER. THE ICON WILL BE DISPLAYED IN ALL USERS